# Is DIL (Dual in Line) a standard?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

Here's a picture of two chips next to each other:
The ATTiny85 and the nRF24l01+.
The ATTiny85 will fit in a standard 8Pin DIL, but the nRF chip won't because the connectors are more tightly spaced together. Does anyone know if there is any "standard" the connections on the nRF24l01+ chip are following? 2x4 pin single in line?

[image]

Comment: The one on the left isn't DIL, it's 0.1" headers.

Comment: The one on the left isn't exactly a chip, either. The 0.1" pitch headers it uses are quite common board-to-board connectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dual In-Line, as applicable to IC packages, is a standard, with the pin pitch of each row being 0.1 inch, and the separation between rows (the *dual* part) being 0.3 inches (JEDEC MS-001) for small pin count packages.

There is also a 0.6 inch row separation DIL package (JEDEC MS-010), for large pin counts. These are commonly known as Wide-DIP ICs.

The nRF device shown is not actually a standard IC package, it just uses a standard pitch 0.1" pin pitch (along both axes) connector. It is not designed to fit into a DIP IC socket. Instead, one would use a dual-row female pin header if soldering onto a board is not desired:

[image: Dual row female pin header] <sub>([source](http://www.globalsources.com/gsol/I/Female-header/p/sm/1017623092.htm))</sub>

---

*Edit*: I [just found out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package#Lead_count_and_spacing) that apparently there are also less common 0.4 inch and 0.9 inch row separation packages, though I have never seen one. Also known are 0.75 inch row spacing packages with a 0.07 inch pin pitch.